# Meaning of "так так так!"

Tags: одним-словом, междометие

I've often heard the interjection "так, так, так!". What does it mean? Can somebody illustrate with examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My impression is that it isn't what Yellow Sky thought it was in his answer. I'd say, on paper, I would expect two completely different meanings and intonations, depending on the number of "так"s:

"Так, так, так!", especially with that prolonged "а" in the last "так" is exactly what Yellow Sky said it was - an expression of interest. They are pronounced slowly, as if you're savoring the moment. I'll just quote his examples to illustrate:

> A teacher comes into the classroom, two pupils are kissing. The teacher says, "Tак, так, та-a-a-aк!"
>
> A guy comes to a police station in Moscow and says, "I'm a CIA agent, I've been spying on the Bolshoi Theater for 5 years." The policeman says, "Tак, так, та-a-a-aк!"

But if I see 4+ "так"s, in my mind I pronounce them faster and I'd expect them to be used to stop the other speaker from continuing. Probably I'd continue the "так"s with "подожди". It means something along the lines of the English "wait, wait, wait". Here's an example to illustrate:

> -- И тут этот парень ударил его прямо в лицо, и...
> -- Так, так, так, так, подожди, имеешь в виду того парня, который перед этим приставал к его жене или того, который пил виски у бара?
> *Meaning:*
> -- And then that guy hits him right in the face and...
> -- Wait, wait, wait, do you mean the guy who was hitting on his wife or the one who was drinking whiskey at the bar?

Comment: Yes, it's with many "tak's" as I've heard it, and very rapidly pronounced.

Answer (score 4):

That can be translated as `Well, well, well!` which means "that's quite interesting." Examples:

> A teacher comes into the classroom, two pupils are kissing. The
>   teacher says, "Tак, так, та-a-a-aк!"

One more:

> A guy comes to a police station in Moscow and says, "I'm a CIA afent,
>   I've been spying on the Bolshoi Theater for 5 years." The policeman
>   says, "Tак, так, та-a-a-aк!"